# C# WebDriver: driver not updating after Page Refresh

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario where I need to load a page, and if something isn't present on it, reload the page until it is.  The page also has ajax content (an IFrame) which contains the content I'm looking for.

The first page load, I am able to find the IFrame and detect the content I am looking for is not present.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Name(frameName)));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
var content = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myContent"));
```

I then call:

```
driver.Navigate().Refresh(); 
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

to reload the page and then call the following again:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Name(frameName)));
```

However the driver's PageSource contains the pre-ajax content of the page despite the fact that I can see the page has had content added to it.  The FindElement call continues to throw until the 30 second timeout occurs.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to reload your parent window to check iframe is present or not.

driver.Navigate().Refresh();

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

With above code, your control is still on iframe &your reloading page, then your switching back to parent window.

You should first switch to parent window and they should try to reload page.
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); //switch to parent window

driver.Navigate().Refresh();